# Question on application of intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Here's a question from Real Analysis textbook:

> Let $p(x)=a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_n x^n$. If $a_0 a_n <0$, show that
>   $p$ has at least two real roots.

I'm not sure how to even prove this and I think this is wrong since the polynomial $p(x)=x^3-x^2+x-1$ satisfies the above conditions but then has only one root.

Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: You seem right to me. Maybe they meant for $n$ to be even?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen that seems likely.

Comment: Yeah, otherwise $n=1$ would be a more obvious counterexample (I guess on that note we should say the degree is even and nonzero.)

Comment: I think I need to show for there is $x_0$ such that $p(\pm x_0) > 0$ and I'll be done (for even degree polynomial, obviously)

Comment: Yep, exactly. IVT implies it from there.